# Downloading Old RSS Contents

Tags: web-scraping, rss, web-crawler, google-reader

I need to have the news of some sites like CNN, BBC, and Reuters for my research. I want to know how I can write a program to download RSS contents of these sites from almost 10 years ago. I used GoogleReaderAPI but it seems silly.

Comment: RSS is just a bunch of specially formed webpages; webpages (or single pages within a portal) can and do disappear much earlier than in 10 years. Your only hope is a) an on-site archive (which will likely require payment), or b) sites like web.archive.org (which doesn't have any guarantees, least of all about site completeness).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSS data will normally not contain aged data like that.  You will likely need to subscribe to a service (AP, All HEadline News, Reuters) that allows you to search archives